# Pass parameter from .sh file to .yml file?

Tags: shell, ansible

I am new to Ansible as well as Ubuntu system also. I want to pass the multiple variables from .sh file to .yml. I have plan to store all input variables in an array then passing the variable one by one using for loop while calling the file `distributed-setup.yml`.

Currently, I am trying to pass a variable.For that,I am following the below steps.

1. While executing the `First.sh` file I am passing the a variables like `First.sh Input.yaml`
2. `First.sh` file is like this

   ```
   echo $1
   ansible-playbook distributed-setup.yml --extra-vars="v:$1" -${1:-v} | tee output.txt
   ```
3. Distributed-setup.yml

   ```
   ---
   - name: Executing slaves
     hosts: slave
     gather_facts: no
     vars:
         v: "{{lookup('env','v') }}"
         contents: "{{ lookup('file','/home/ubuntu/Ansible-setup/Distributed-Ubuntu-Setup/Input/Input.yaml') | from_yaml }}"
         log: "{{ contents['log'][0] }}"
         timeout: "{{ contents['ansible-timeout'][0] }}"
   ```

In the line, contents: I need to use variable 'v' instead of Input.yaml.

How to do this?

Comment: I'd suggest "to Ansible playbook" rather than "to .yml file" in the title -- YAML is used for much more than Ansible, and this is a very Ansible-specific technique (most YAML parsers don't do template expansion of content they've read).

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest ways to do this is through the environment

```
someVar=value ansible-playbook ...
```

and then, inside your Ansible code, you can refer to `ansible_env.someVar`. You can also `export` the variable and not need to define it on the same line.

---

To make this a bit more concrete for your use case:

```
input_yaml=/home/ubuntu/Ansible-setup/Distributed-Ubuntu-Setup/Input/Input.yaml
export input_yaml
ansible-playbook distributed-setup.yml
```

...and in your Ansible file:

```
contents: "{{ lookup('file', ansible_env.input_yaml) | from_yaml }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could use your variable `v` within other ones:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    v: "{{ lookup('env','v') }}"
    b: "{{ lookup('file','/tmp/{{ v }}') | from_yaml }}"

  tasks:
  - name: set contents
    set_fact:
      contents: "{{ lookup('file','/tmp/{{ v }}') | from_yaml }}"

  - name: debug
    debug:
      msg: "{{ b }} == {{ contents }}"
    when: b == contents
```

`v` will get the value of the existing environment var `v` and then use it on var `b` later in a task just in case is created another variable named `contents` with the value of `b`  in this case using [set_fact](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/set_fact_module.html)

For testing do:

```
$ export v=foo
$ date > /tmp/foo
$ ansible-playbook test.yml
```

It will set `v` to `foo` then will create a file in `/tmp/foo` with the current date (output of the `date` command)